# Encoding xml as ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, xml-serialization, iso-8859-1

I sent an xml file which I created while serializing an object and received a response that it is incorrect and not well-formed:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Moreover, I am supposed to use ISO-8859-1.

I assume that I not only have to change `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`, but additionally I have to create the file during serialization from the code already with encoding ISO-8859-1. Correct?

I am doint it this way:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); 
   
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
                Indent = true,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                Encoding = encoding
};

XmlDocument xd = null;

using (MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memStm, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
          ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, input);
    }
    memStm.Position = 0;
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    using (var xtr = XmlReader.Create(memStm, settings))
    {
          xd = new XmlDocument();
          xd.Load(xtr);
    }
}

byte[] file = encoding.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml);
```

I used a framework to find out what encoding my created files have and when I create them with ISO-8859-1 as above my encoding checker gives me ASCII, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> I sent an xml file which I created while serializing an object and received a response that it is incorrect and not well-formed:

The `ï»¿` chars represents a BOM (byte-order-mark) for utf-8 files. That BOM can be a part of utf-8 encoded files. So your xml is valid if read properly.
More information about BOM: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1

> I assume that I not only have to change `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`, but additionally I have to create the file during serialization from the code already with encoding ISO-8859-1. Correct?

Correct.

> I used a framework to find out what encoding my created files have and when I create them with ISO-8859-1 as above my encoding checker gives me ASCII, is that correct?

So, the encoding of a text file cannot be determined exactly, but only "guessed" by means of an analysis. Various encodings have the same code pages for the ASCII characters, therefore ASCII is suitable as result.